# CV writing on a creative way

Tags: resume, job-search

I would like to replace my traditional MS Word based CV. I am looking for solutions, that are as lightweight and portable as a PDF formatted document.
Do you have maybe some ideas how to do it?

Comment: Why make it harder to read your CV? Do you not want a job?

Comment: There are many questions here (such as the duplicate) which discuss alternative resume/CV formats. Take some time to browse through the [tag:resume] questions and look, right now it's not really clear what you are asking and it appears you are asking a duplicate of one of many different questions.

Comment: Even if you were a graphic designer you should stick to a basic readable format.  They just want information about you.

Answer (score 2):

A résumé or CV should be a concise, easily scanned list of what you've accomplished, organized chronologically by position, plus any particularly notable skills.

PDF is definitely the way to go, so that you don't have to worry about formatting problems. And it will probably be read electronically, so you can do the reader a favor by including lots of relevant links; for example, to a personal site demonstrating your work. This will make it a "living" document. See [10 Things that Define a Killer Resume](http://www.squawkfox.com/2008/11/17/10-things-that-define-a-killer-resume/) and [Ask a Manager](http://www.askamanager.org/) for some good tips.

Most importantly, *don't get fancy*. Be concise and clear!